# Insert empty value using Bindparam without error Incorrect Integer value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindparam

I want to insert some data into my MySql table using PDO. If it's not empty it will have Integer datatype so i use PDO::PARAM_INT, but the problem is this data is not required so sometimes it's empty.

It make me have an error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value.

So is it anyway I can pass this empty value variable into my database without having error when it have empty value? here's my code snippet:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (:column)");
$stmt->bindParam(':column',$_POST['value'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An empty *string* is incorrect *integer* value all the same. Although been permissive in the past, nowadays MySQL tends to be more strict with types, enforcing the [STRICT MODE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) by default, hence not accepting an empty string for the integer field anymore.

Besides, PDO::PARAM_INT *doesn't cast* your values.

Therefore, you have to cast them manually

In case you want to retain a possible NULL value, convert your input like this

```
$value = is_null($_POST['value']) ? null : (int)$_POST['value'];
```

If you want to just convert to integer unconditionally, then just make it

```
$value = (int)$_POST['value'];
```

Both snippets will convert an empty string to 0 which will be gladly accepted by MySQL

Comment: so it's not possible to use Bindparam in this case?

Comment: nice, but may i know why bindparam is ugly and useless? is it batter to sanitizing than using bindparam or there is any saver way than this?

Comment: there is no difference between NULL and null, so I dont see how it would be solved that way

Comment: also casting a null to int , will store 0 in the db, it will not set the field to NULL

Answer (score -2):

In My Case I use like this:

```
if(empty($_POST['value'])){ $value = NULL; } else { $value = $_POST['value']; }
$stmt->bindParam(':column', $value);
```

It works Best for me, try from your side :-)